# Is there another runtime model then one-jvm-per-module-instance in Spring Cloud Data Flow?

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-xd

Currently, we are using Spring XD for data ingestion with many many streams (and modules). Unfortunately Spring XD is discontinued and we have to look around for an alternative.

So, we had a look on Spring Cloud Data Flow, because we want to have the dynamic deployment of streams via the shell.

Unfortunately, the simple stream `"http | log"` took **1,6 GB RAM**. Then I launched it a second time, and both streams took **3.2 GB RAM**...

Normally I really agree, that scaling via processes is a good thing.. but to do that with Java and Spring Boot and its immense consumption of RAM it becomes pretty fast ridicules.

For us this is very critical, becuase in the clouds we are using RAM equals money :-(

So, Is there another runtime model - more Spring XD like - in Spring Cloud Data Flow which is more conservative when it comes to RAM usage?

Answer (score 2):

At this time, we do not wish to provide our own containers, and we are pretty committed to the microservice model for Spring Cloud Data Flow. That shouldn't necessarily result in high memory consumption. Microservices (including ones based on Spring Boot) can run very lean when properly tuned. A lot of times, the memory usage that you see is a product of the default settings of the VM, uncollected garbage and so on.

Also, Spring Cloud Data Flow is currently under development, and the current experience is not necessarily the final one. In other words, there's lots of room for improvement.

Can you describe a little what you are doing? In particular, I would be interested in the following:

1) What version of Spring Cloud Data Flow have you been using?
  2) What type of deployer are you using (local, CF, other)
  3) How are you measuring memory consumption?

Cheers,
Marius

PS: Also, regarding Spring XD, 'discontinued' does not properly reflect the current and future status. For a more accurate statement, I would strongly encourage reading this: http://projects.spring.io/spring-xd/#announcement

Comment: > 1) What version of Spring Cloud Data Flow have you been using? 2) What type of deployer are you using (local, CF, other) 3) How are you measuring memory consumption?

 1. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/commit/5039639b6d77bcf737ddb63dd25193b3e6d463dd
 2. 
Local, Bosch IoT Cloud (CF), lattice, AWS
 3. Linux tools to observe memory consumption of OS processes (top)

Answer (score 0):

> At this time, we do not wish to provide our own containers, and we are pretty committed to the microservice model for Spring Cloud Data Flow

So, Spring XD, which is based on containers, is discontinued.

> That shouldn't necessarily result in high memory consumption. Microservices (including ones based on Spring Boot) can run very lean when properly tuned.

Plz, stay concrete and do not talk about Microservices. This term is almost always misinterpreted. We are talking about Spring streams, where a stream consists of chained modules and a module is implemented in Java.

We have different kinds of streams. A representative one looks like that:

```
"receive-data (http) | transform-data | enrich-data | store-data (rabbit, mongodb, etc.)"
```

With Spring Cloud Data Flow each step (module) is run in its own JVM. And I totally agree that this is a good thing to enable horizontal scaling. But please keep the level of granularity in mind. A module has more likely the granularity of a function call, than a Microservices (oh no, I've said it).

Let’s assume that we optimized our modules in a way that each instance consumes max 256MB of memory on average (and this very optimistic).

- For our stream above this means 256MB x 4 modules = 1GB
- At least we deploy each stream twice to have some HA -> 2GB
- Multiplied by the number of different streams in your system...

That may work for a small number of streams and modules, but explodes very fast...

For my department this is critical enought that we begin to stop using Spring XD... And I really hate it, because I love Spring XD and its containers! For me, Spring XD is the best working solution to establish scalable data ingestion and the best compromise between resource costs, the freedom to use Java and scalability.